# Delete first two characters of an alphanumeric sequence in a column

Tags: character, excel-2010, alphanumeric

I'm trying to scan a column for character size. If the alphanumerical character size is met (qty 12), then the first two characters will be deleted. They will always be specific numbers (10).  See below.

```
H063088955
F243066424
10G403085387
F253066457
E473057375
G503087343
10H303098124
G093075912
G433084322
10G403085388
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Sub qwerty()
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If Len(v) = 12 Then
            r.Value = Mid(v, 3)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```